# Fix clock settings on STM32F105 with 25MHz oscillator

Tags: stm32, uart, clock

Noob here :)

While reverse engineering a CAN bus filter module:
[image]
Using existing code from Github: https://github.com/EliasKotlyar/Canfilter

It appears that the clock settings aren't correct because `HAL_Delay(1000);` actually delays for ~0.3 seconds, and UART5 via PC12 pin works with actually 3 times higher baud rate than configured:

```
huart5.Instance = UART5;
huart5.Init.BaudRate = 9600; // requires ~28800 baud rate on the monitor side
huart5.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart5.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart5.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart5.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
huart5.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
huart5.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
```

Here is clock configuration:
[image]

And my noob question is what's wrong with the configuration, or probably the issue is in another area?

Comment: 25MHz seems a tad high for the crystal. 8MHz would be a more reasonable frequency methinks. With that in mind, the baud rate and tick rate would be more correct.

Comment: You need to check that the `SystemCoreClockUpdate` function in system_stm32f1xx.c is being given the correct `HSE_VALUE`. It's defined as 25M in stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h - but I can't see how system_stm32f1xx.c includes that .h file. If it doesn't see that 25M value then it'll default to 8M, and this would explain your apparent 3x speedup. You could try adding an explicit `#include "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h"` to the start of system_stm32f1xx.c and see if that helps.

Comment: @brhans you are correct - the issue is with ignored "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h" file. I'm using Platformio IDE and it doesn't deal with the custom config file, but includes it from the common lib location. Weird but true: https://community.platformio.org/t/stm32f1xx-hal-conf-h-ignored-or-is-it-something-else/15880

Comment: Odometer tampering, are we?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany no, my idea is to customize behavior of multimedia buttons which work via CAN. For odometer tampering this device works out of the box :)

Comment: That's reassuring, lol. I guess the problem wouldn't have shown up in the STM32CubeIDE environment. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in Platformio IDE which I'm using. It ignores the "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h" file: https://community.platformio.org/t/stm32f1xx-hal-conf-h-ignored-or-is-it-something-else/15880

How to resolve this particular issue - put appropriate define in platformio.ini file: `build_flags = -D HSE_VALUE=25000000`

But overall the configs which are made in STMCube32IDE and stored in "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h" file aren't transferred into Platformio. Instead a common "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h" file from library folder is used. It seems to be known but unressolvable issue.